# submitting a field with just enter button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I submit a form (it may be just one field, i will give example in a second) with just 'enter' button, without showing a submit button to the user, or even placing it in a code at all?

right now i have:

```
= form_tag admin_users_path, :method => 'get'
= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter]
```

and after clicking 'enter' it sends me to the `Admin::UsersController`, but `params[:filter]` is blank, however my information is displayed by "better_errors" in QUESRY_STRING and REQUEST_URL. Any ideas how can i make this work?

EDIT

Solution WITHOUT form_tag would be very much appreciated, it keep screwing with my css...

Comment: Of course, `text_field` not in form tag. Surround it with block.

Comment: i dont get it. as you can see above it is not nested...

Comment: It doesn't matter. I mean, you can insert in form any tag.

Comment: Also you can do it with `jquery`. Make a trigger on submit button, and send ajax request with you params, extracted from fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
= form_tag admin_users_path, :method => 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter]
```

If you want just a link [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898737/pass-parameter-by-link-to-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: thank you sir, i've decided to just use simple_form;)

Comment: You'll have to remove `-end` or you'll get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

> Solution WITHOUT form_tag would be very much appreciated, it keep
>   screwing with my css...

[HTML sends data through forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), and if you wanted to submit a `text_field` with enter, you'll have to use a simple form to define both the submission path & which data to send

Therefore, the two ways you can use are either to use JS, or a form to submit the field:

---

**form_tag**

```
   = form_tag admin_users_path, :method => 'get'
       = text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter]
```

This will submit with `enter`, and to fix your css, just amend the styles to work with the form. If you're scrimping on this fundamental html functionality

---

**JS**

The other option will  be to mimic the [submission of an HTML form with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414713/creating-form-in-javascript-without-html-form):

```
$('element').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
         $.post(url, { value1: $(this).val() } );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

<%= f.search_field :title_cont, placeholder:"Search" %>

**<%= f.submit %>**  <-------(1)
<% end %>

you just need to remove the "=" sign form the arrowed line or line (1) like
**<% f.submit %>**

Comment: i want to say, just don't show the button but button will always be there like <% f.submit %> instead of <%= f.submit %>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).